# having users index for admin and normal users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to have the users index page to list the admin and normal users separately, the below where you can select the Student or Admin view, via what I'd presume would be links...

Index view for users...

```
<h1>Listing users</h1>

<p><b><u>Students</u></b> <u>Admins</u></p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Login count</th>
  </tr>

<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.login_count %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<p><%= link_to 'New User', new_admin_user_path %></p>
```

In my Users controller

```
class Admin::UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_admin_user

    def index
      # @users = User.admin 
      @users = User.students.paginate page: params[:page], order: 'created_at desc', per_page: 20

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render :json => @users }
      end
    end
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by separately? Should you list only normal or only admin users? Admin users in one table and normal users in another table?

Comment: that's correct. want separate tables for each

Comment: Why can't you just add a "where is an admin" or "where isn't an admin" to your `User.students`?

Comment: I want to have a separate table for the admins and student users. Am I best to have another view? or can it be done in this one nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're set on having two different tables for the two then doing another view would be the easiest way. The top links could be just how you want them.

```
<p><b><u><%= link_to 'Students', user_path %></u></b> <u><%= link_to 'Admin', admin_path %></u></p>
```

Is there a reason you're set against having a table combining all users and then a column to differentiate if they're an admin? That would make it a lot easier to do what you're looking for.

Comment: yeah i think this is the way to go. it's just that there will be hundreds of users and only a few admins and it will be much easier to navigate this way as i need the newest users to be shown first

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer depends on which differences there are between a normal user (students?) and an administrator and what do you want to show about these kind of users.

If you want to show just which users are administrator you could get a parameter in your Users#index action to show only administrators (I don't know if it's the Rails way).

If you want to show more/different information for Students/Administrators maybe it's better to have a model for Students and another for Administrators that extend User model with separate controllers and switch between the #index actions of them.

Could you explain better what kind of information do you need to maintain/show? Thanks

Comment: It will be very similar information, just want to separate the two types of users. but don't want two tables showing on the one page, the user index page.